# Laravel-elixir with gulp

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I have the following problem:
I copied a private project from github. To get it working I have to use "npm install" (the package.json is not made by me).
After that the project should be build with the "gulp" command. Sadly it doesn_t work and I get following error:

```
\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\index.js:21
recipe(Elixir.mixins);
TypeError: recipe is not a function
at global.Elixir (c:\path\to\project\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\index.js:21:5)
```

Here are my versions:
Gulp: CLI version 1.2.2 Local version 3.9.1
node: 6.4.0
npm: 3.10.3

And my gulpfile:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir();
```

Edit:
And the package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9"
  }
}
```

I don't know if this is enough information so solve the problem, and I know that this is a very specific problm, but maybe someone has an answer at hand or can give me tips to find the mistake.

Comment: please post your package.json so the versions can be seen there.  Sometimes you have to tweak the versions before you do `npm install`

Comment: edited the package.json in

Comment: is that your entire package.json?

Comment: yes, that's the package.json

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir

> If you are developing on a Windows system or you are running your VM
>   on a Windows host system, you may need to run the npm install command
>   with the --no-bin-links switch enabled:
>
> `npm install --no-bin-links`

That could it be it my friend.

Comment: I'm actually on winows. Sadly that didn't help either. I still get the same error.